# Redirecting domain (not google apps) to appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I'm building a application that supports different domains. A small CMS that supports different domains.

But what I can't figure out is how to redirect other domains that's outside google apps. I have a domain at google apps, that work's perfectly. 
When I create a cname that points at either my appid.appspot.com or www.appsdomain.com it just goes to google.com.

What do I need to do so the other domains point to my appengine application.

..fredrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use a cname because google needs to know how to direct the requests through their infrastructure to your app.

You should follow the instructions here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html to set up your name with their infrastructure so that requests to the cname get routed correctly.

Update: You do not have to move your domain to google, only inform them of the names you are going to set up cnames to point to them.

Comment: I've read the article you provided, but want I don't really understand is if I register the domain with google apps does this move the domain? Since I have other subdomain that need to remain the same.

Comment: Google Apps doesn't do any magic; only subdomains you send to Google's servers with your DNS setup use Google's services.  If you have A or CNAME records for a subdomain pointing elsewhere, they'll continue to work exactly as they do now.

Comment: That article only mentions how to use Google Apps to register a domain for an App Engine app. Your update ("Update: You do not have to move your domain to google, only inform them of the names you are going to set up cnames to point to them.") -- how is that done?

Comment: @dplass you follow the instructions at the link listed above.  In short - you click "add domain" and enter the domain, then create the cname to point to ghs.google.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without a cname.

You need to set up a redirection mechanism of your second domain name. You can do that either by telling your registrar to redirect that url to your Google Apps url (that's how I do it with my registrar, [name.com](http://www.name.com)), or you could set up a small [php] script on a server you manage that would receive the queries on the second domain and issue a 301 redirect to your Google Apps domain.

EDIT: It all depends on what you want to do. If you want your app to live at both urls, then this solution will not work. I wrote this in the idea that you want the second url to redirect to your main url, if that's not what you want to do, then issuing redirects won't do the trick.

Comment: Just about to ask about that. What I need to get work is that the app i live at several domains.